# Using mocha chai with Nodejs error: no test specified

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-immutable

I am trying to set up Mocha and Chai for the first time. However, I am getting error message: "No test specified" when I type "npm run test" on the command line. In my package.json file, I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test:":"mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive"
```

I have a test folder in my root with two files:

```
// test/testhelper.js

import chai from 'chai';
import chaiImmutable from'chai-immutable';

chai.use(chaiImmutable);
```

// test/immutablespec.js

```
import {expect} from 'chai';

describe('immutability', () => {

    describe('a number', () => {

        function increment(currentState){
            return currentState + 1;    
        }
        it('is immutable',() => {
            let state = 42;
            let nextState=increment(state);

            expect(nextState).to.equal(43);
            expect(state).to.equal(42);

        });
    });
});
```

The exact message on my console is

```
react-hot-boilerplate@1.0.0 test c:\users\owner\react\voting (my root)
echo 'Error:not test specified'
```

It appears that anything I type in my test script in package.json gets ignored and I get the exact same error msg each time.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told mocha where your tests are. You should point it at your `test` folder:

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test
```

Comment: Still getting the same error msg. Even if I type gibberish under script test, it seems to be ignored and I get the same msg. I have no problem when I type npm start but having problem with npm run test.

Comment: Run the command I suggested directly in the command line. Does it work outside of package.json?

Comment: yes it does work in command line. So my problem now is why the test script is not read in my package.json. even though npm start script runs fine.

Comment: oops, ignore that. Typo - I had two colons. Thanks!

Comment: btw it wasn't necessary to specify ./test. Mocha still manages to find the test file.